# JScript: Protractor and Jasmine reporters

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am really new with programming and developing (I know exactly 1 syntax) but I want to test a part of a website and also generate an output report. Protractor is  working quite alright, but I cant seem to get the reporter to work.

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
allScriptsTimeout: 15000,
//baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['x.js'],
framework: 'jasmine2',
rootElement: '.ocf-widget-savings',

multiCapabilities: [ 


{
    'browserName': 'chrome',

},



],

onPrepare: function(){

    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
    capsPromise.then(function(caps){
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
        var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
        var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        var htmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            filePrefix: prePendStr+'xmloutput',
            savePath: 'Testing Protractor/testresults'
        }));

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new htmlScreenshotReporter({
                dest: './screenshots',
                captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
                filename: prePendStr+'my-report.html'
            })
            );

    });     

},
```

Its now throwing the following error

> var result = fn();

does anyone have any clue about what I am doing wrong here? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please edit your question to include the full error message. Also, please trim down your `protractor.conf.js` file so that it only includes the essential part of the problem. It will be easier for us to understand and it just may help you solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The answer below solved the issue though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an installation problem.

Do:

npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0

and try again.